# For loop not incrementing the date upwards

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below code that is adding 4 dates to an array but the date remains the same for each value in the array. 
It just gives me 4 values of 2014/01/24 instead of 2014/01/24, 2014/01/31, 2014/02/07, 2014/02/14

Thanks

```
        $myArray = array(); 

        // Number of days
        $days = get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-inc_recur_freq', true);

         // cycle from 1st week's due date to the end of payment cycle
        for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {

             $myArray[] = date($mysqldate, strtotime("+" . $days . " days"));

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will give you four copies of the same date, because you're simply adding a fixed number of days to the current date each time.

I think you probably want to change your `for` loop to be:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $myArray[] = date($mysqldate, strtotime("+" . ($days * $i) . " days"));
}
```

Note that I've changed the loop to run `0..3` instead of `1..4`, on the assumption that the first date you want is today. If the first date you actually want is `$days` days beyond today, revert to using `1..4`.

---

You can see this in action in the following PHP code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("EST");
$myArray = array();
$days = 7;
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $myArray[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+" . ($days * $i) . " days"));
}
var_dump($myArray);
```

which outputs (using [one of the online PHP executors](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)):

```
array(4) {
    [0]=> string(10) "2014-01-24"
    [1]=> string(10) "2014-01-31"
    [2]=> string(10) "2014-02-07"
    [3]=> string(10) "2014-02-14"
}
```

---

However, it *may* be that your actual `$days` variable is set to zero (you seem to think it will be set to seven). A `$days` value of zero would cause all dates to be today even with the corrected code above, so I'd be checking that. One *possibility* for the value being set to zero is your unusual mixture of underscores and hyphens in the key you're looking up:

```
wpcf-inc_recur_freq
    ^   ^     ^
    |   |     |
    |   +-----+------- underscore
    +----------------- hyphen
```

I suspect you didn't quite press as hard on the SHIFT key as you should have when entering that first `_` character :-)

Comment: is it ($days * $i)  or ($days + $i)

Comment: @user1844933, it's definitely multiplicatiion `*`. Assuming `$days` is 7, you want 7 * 0, 7 * 1, 7 * 2 and so on.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean and have made the changes but it's still not working for some reason. Still just looping over the same date

Comment: @user537137, then there's something wrong with your code that you haven't shown. As per my test run on the PHP online executor, this runs fine. However, it's likely that your `$days` variable is not set correctly, I'll update to check that.

Answer (score 1):

You're not incrementing $days in the loop, so it will give the same value each time the loop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing $days in your loop.

```
$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d');

// Number of days
$days = get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-inc_recur_freq', true);

// cycle from 1st week's due date to the end of payment cycle
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $myArray[] = date($mysqldate, strtotime("+" . $i*$days . " days"));
}
var_dump($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
         $mysqldate = date('Y-m-d');

        // Number of days
        $days = get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-inc_recur_freq', true);

        // cycle from 1st week's due date to the end of payment cycle
        for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
            $myArray[$i] = date($mysqldate, strtotime("+" . $i*$days . " days"));
        }
        var_dump($myArray);
```